# How to override a protected method using PXProtectedAccess?

Tags: acumatica

I need to override the Service Contract Schedule's Next Execution Date when a Service Order is generated. This automatically calculated depending on the occurrence setup. The calculation doesn't fit my requirements though so I need to override it.

[image]

Looking at the source I found the method that I need to override. Its protected unfortunately.

[image]

I found this [gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66568715/unable-to-use-protected-method-override-in-acumatica-graph-extension) but I'm not getting such luck. Not sure what am I missing here ? My code as follows :

```
[PXProtectedAccess]
public abstract class ServiceContractInqExt1 : PXGraphExtension<ServiceContractInq>
{
    [PXProtectedAccess]
    protected abstract void UpdateGeneratedSchedule(int scheduleID, DateTime? toDate, DateTime? lastGeneratedElementDate, FSSchedule fsScheduleRow);
}

public class ServiceContractInqExt2: PXGraphExtension<ServiceContractInqExt1,ServiceContractInq>
{
    #region Event Handlers
    public static bool IsActive()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public delegate void UpdateGeneratedScheduleDelegate(int scheduleID, DateTime? toDate, DateTime? lastGeneratedElementDate, FSSchedule fsScheduleRow);
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void UpdateGeneratedSchedule(int scheduleID, DateTime? toDate, DateTime? lastGeneratedElementDate, FSSchedule fsScheduleRow,UpdateGeneratedScheduleDelegate baseMethod)
    {
      PXTrace.WriteInformation("HIT !");//this is not firing !
      baseMethod(scheduleID, toDate, lastGeneratedElementDate, fsScheduleRow);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

EDIT :
Following the answer below.

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.FS.Scheduler;
using PX.SM;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.FS;

namespace PX.Objects.FS
{
  [PXProtectedAccess]
  public abstract class AAServiceContractInqExtension : PXGraphExtension<ServiceContractInq>
  {
      [PXProtectedAccess]
      protected void UpdateGeneratedSchedule(int scheduleID, DateTime? toDate, DateTime? lastGeneratedElementDate, FSSchedule fsScheduleRow)
      {
          PXTrace.WriteInformation("HIT");
      }
  }  
}
```

And simply loading the page is raising an error.

[image]

My Acumatica build/version

[image]

Comment: you should use PXOverride to "override" a method and change its logic. If you need to call a protected method you declare it with PXProtectedAccess as an abstract and then in your code in the graph extension call to the abstract method (which at runtime will be the base protected method). In both cases make your override or protected access members public. So If you want new logic for UpdateGeneratedSchedule you would use PXOverride. If you want to call UpdateGeneratedSchedule then you use PXProtectedAccess as an abstract member.

Comment: [PXOverride] will not work in this instance because the underlying methods are not marked as virtual.

Comment: Ah I did not catch we are talking about a non virtual protected method. Thanks @JoshuaVanHoesen for clarifying. Another reason for all of us Acumatica devs to always stick in the virtual keyword for all  protected and public graph methods. Make the next dev's life easier :)

Comment: @Brendan so this cannot be done ? Is there any other way to customise the updating of the NextExecutionDate ?

Comment: @Rick without virtual you miss out on using these attributes but it looks like Joshua has a working alternative solution. It is really the closest available virtual method to override to do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you will be unable to override the method `UpdateGeneratedSchedule` due to the fact that it is not marked as `virtual` so even with access to the `ContractGenerationEnqBase` graph we cannot modify its functionality.

With that in mind I successfully implemented the following solution

```
public class ServiceContractInqExtension : PXGraphExtension<ServiceContractInq>
{
    public delegate void ProcessServiceContractDelegate(PXCache cache, FSContractSchedule fsScheduleRow, DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate);

    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void processServiceContract(PXCache cache, FSContractSchedule fsScheduleRow, DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate, ProcessServiceContractDelegate del)
    {
        del?.Invoke(cache, fsScheduleRow, fromDate, toDate);
        UpdateGeneratedSchedule(fsScheduleRow.ScheduleID, new DateTime(2023, 3, 11));
    }

    protected void UpdateGeneratedSchedule(int? scheduleID, DateTime nextExecutionDate)
    {
                PXUpdate<Set<FSSchedule.nextExecutionDate, Required<FSSchedule.nextExecutionDate>>, FSSchedule,
                Where<
                    FSSchedule.scheduleID, Equal<Required<FSSchedule.scheduleID>>>>
                .Update(Base, nextExecutionDate, scheduleID);
    }
}
```

Once the processing method has been completed the custom `UpdateGeneratedSchedule` will utilize PXUpdate to set the desired field value. PXUpdate being the same call used by the method you originally wanted to override.

Here we can see one of the schedules before processing

[image: Base Schedule]

After our custom code has been called we can see that the 'Next Execution Date' is the value provided to our custom method.

[image: Modified Schedule]

Comment: Thanks but doesn't seems to work. In fact I'm getting an error simply loading the page.

Comment: To clarify, you are receiving an error when loading the page FS305100 "Service Contract Schedule"? Also if you could provide what version / build you are utilizing. The build I used was 21R106.0024

Comment: No. ServiceContractInq is screenID FS500300. Its the graph that generates the service order based on contract schedule. And will schedule the next service based on recurrence configured in the contract schedule. I've updated my question to show additional screenshots. cheers !

Comment: This is turning out to be a more complex resolution than anticipated due to the fact non of the methods within the graph are marked as *virtual* meaning we cannot utilize the [PXOverride] attribute.

Comment: @Rick Sorry for the delay, I have updated my answer after verifying the solution through testing of the process.